# Unable to set Data Colors from Format option in Power BI

Tags: node.js, typescript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In my custom Power BI code I have used 'Data Colors' options. I am pushing data points to be further used as shown below:

```
this.dataPoints.push({
    category: String(categories.values[index]),
    value: Number(dataValues.values[index]),
    color: getCategoricalObjectValue<Fill>(categories, index, 'colorSelector', 'fill', defaultColor).solid.color,
    selectionId: this.host.createSelectionIdBuilder().withCategory(categories, index).createSelectionId()
})
```

I have used helper file containing definition for `getCategoricalObjectValue` function. Definition of function is as shown:

```
export function getCategoricalObjectValue<T>(category: DataViewCategoryColumn, index: number, objectName: string, propertyName: string, defaultValue: T): T {
    let categoryObjects = category.objects;

    if (categoryObjects) {
        let categoryObject: DataViewObject = categoryObjects[index];
        if (categoryObject) {
            let object = categoryObject[objectName];
            if (object) {
                let property: T = object[propertyName];
                if (property !== undefined) {
                    return property;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

I am facing issue with `getCategoricalObjectValue` function where `category.objects` always comes to be undefined irrespective of when color has been changed from Format menu.

I need help to resolve above issue. All code I have used is based on example given on https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals for Bar Chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the existing code which is deprecated or the implementation has changed lately.

The solution is given in the link provided below:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-sampleBarChart/issues/5